# azure AD SPA using auth code flow with PKCE in react app

Tags: azure, authorization, single-page-application, client-side

I'm trying to not let my users sign in again and again whenever it comes to use the app after logging in once, and for that I'm trying to generate refresh token (already having accessToken and authorization code and also idToken, using auth code flow), and refresh the access token using refresh token.

I have a doubt whether I can generate refresh token without the use of backend server or not using auth flow and PKCE or if I need backend then how to process it. Or else are there some other ways such that I can prevent a logged in user log in again? Can somebody help me with that?

For that I've registered an azure app and got the credentials for the app from there. from the docs of azure [link to azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios#scenarios-and-supported-authentication-flows) I found that there are only two types of available flows : implicit flow and auth code grant [image: image from above mentioned doc].
In the documentation of implicit flow it is mentioned to prefer auth flow, so I decided to follow that and go with auth code flow but now I'm stuck as how to get refresh token for further use.

Comment: Use the authorization code flow + PKCE. You can look at [my code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure) and [blog posts](https://authguidance.com/azure-active-directory-setup/) to progress your setup and see how things look. Note that my app also receives a refresh token. though it is not really recommended to use one in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should use the [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). Implicit flow is no longer recommended for SPA applications.

You can't configure the lifetime of a refresh token. You can't reduce or lengthen their lifetime. [Configure sign-in frequency in Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime) to define the time periods before a user is required to sign in again. For more information, see Configuring authentication session management with Conditional Access.

Not all refresh tokens follow the rules set in the token lifetime policy. Specifically, refresh tokens used in single page apps are always fixed to 24 hours of activity, as if they have a MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor policy of 24 hours applied to them.